# Is it safe to delete the Windows logs folder?

Tags: windows, logging, cleaning

Is it safe to delete the contents of the following Windows logs folder: `C:\Windows\Logs` (OS: Windows Vista)

```
 Directory of c:\Windows\Logs

10-02-2009  21:23    <DIR>          .
10-02-2009  21:23    <DIR>          ..
18-06-2011  20:08    <DIR>          CBS
30-01-2009  11:54    <DIR>          DPX
07-07-2011  13:03    <DIR>          SystemRestore
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  14,071,410,688 bytes free
```

Comment: Let me ask a short question here: Why?

Comment: It seems to be huge in size and just want to make sure it doesn't accumulate unwanted files. If it's like a temp folder, can't I just remove the contents?

Comment: Ah those people who always have to question and second-guess you! Personally I want to delete it because the Windows 7 OS is hoarding all my hard drive (about 35 gigs at this point). So since Windows is not cleaning up it's own crap (like a spoiled teenager), I have to do it myself.

Comment: @Joshua could you maybe give us an update, on whether it is safe to delete? (as answer or comment)

Answer (score 2):

Log usually may have their function just to register some events for future analisis, as definition you shouldn't have any problems when deleting logs. However, if you want to take a try, save a backup image from your disk (with clonezilla or similar for example), delete your logs and test your system for some time. If anything wrong happends then your log clean was sucessfull.
PS: Dont forget to post your results here on superuser please :D

Comment: There is more than just log files in that folder though. There are also database logs, which cannot be deleted.

Comment: If there are vitable files on this folder, so Windows must block the deletion of this files as it does on another files. Moreover, if its vital, so this folder should'nt be called "Logs".

Comment: I did not write the software, so while I agree with you in general, that is not the case. The log files for the System Restore database are there, and are not named .log.

Comment: On my system the System Restore database have ".etl" extension. As I know, etl files are log files from Windows Performance Toolkit, and can be opened with the "xperfview" component of WPT. However, it is still log files as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe, I was just going by the 10,000K file size, typical for Microsoft database logs. I would still like to wait for him to tell me what files are in what sub-folder.

Comment: I've added the contents of the folder as part of the question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is generally, no, but some of the sub-folders maybe. Which sub-folders have the most data, and give me an idea of what it looks like.